# Acceptance tests

Tags: java, android, ruby, тестирование, gems

Есть такое понятие как тесты в приложении, некоторые думают что это хорошо, полезно и их надо писать, другие же считают что главное чтоб приложуха ехала как надо. Ну так вот обозначу, я стараюсь быть всё таки из первой команды.

Ближе к вопросу, когда мы пишем тесты это одно, но есть нечто такое - чему я ещё не знаю определения, когда мы пишем тесты для тестов, проверяя тем самым нашу 'статистику' по тестам - в процентном соотношении.
+ Ко всему прочему устанавливают homebrew(если у Вас mac), ruby и прочие атрибуты.

В принципе ясно почему это всё делается, но не совсем, плюс хотелось бы каких то дополнений для изучения, чтоб знать как к этому можно удачно зайти.

Comment: Немного не понял, причём тут homebrew и ruby? У вас тесты их устанавливают?

Comment: @NickVolynkin для так называемых acceptance tests

Answer (score 1):

Acceptance test - приемочные тесты. Это тесты которые проверяют высокоуровневую функциональность обычно они пишутся по user story. В Ruby эти тесты обычно пишут используя Cucumber.

Тестировать тесты - это что-то очень непонятное. Возможно вы имели ввиду покрытие - Test Coverage. Это можно посчитать при помощи simplecov.

Answer (score 0):

Тут два понятия выделяются, которые вы можете дальше гуглить, если интересно:

1. "Настройка тестового окружения" -- она же provisioning. Здесь могут быть задействованы [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) или [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). А можно сохранять настроенное окружение в образ и гонять через [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) например. В некоторых случаях может пригодиться [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), но следует хорошо подумать, [что именно вам нужно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16647069/322020), и нужно ли.
2. Тестирование тестов -- вполне имеющая место быть процедура. Бывают такие случаи, как:

   - тестирование накопленных хелперов, библиотек -- если у вас накопились сложные хелперы для Selenium-тестирования ([Capybara](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara)) страниц веб-приложения, то можете сделать простейшую (м.б. даже статическую) страницу, чтоб на ней проверять, что хелперы не сломались
   - статическая проверка, что библиотеку используют правильно: что не используют deprecated методы или придерживаются каких-то рекомендаций или особенностей подхода к тестированию конкретного приложения -- если хочется мучений, то можно привинтить сюда rubocop, но следует максимально критично относиться к этой фигне, потому что автор упорот
   - динамическая проверка, что библиотеку используют правильно: был у меня случай, когда кто-то плохо читал доки по синтаксису [factory girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) и [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker) неправильно генерировал объекты (имена были не уникальны) -- созданием тысячи экземпляров каждого класса удавалось найти коллизии